# How to set the tintColor for Navigationbar in ios7

Tags: uitableview, uinavigationbar, uitoolbar, ios7

Hi I have to port one of my project from ios6 to ios7. While porting I had come across few issues those are mentioning below.Please help me to resolve these issues.

1. one is setting the tintcolor as default for Toolbar & NavigationBar. Actually I can able to set the tintcolor as default for the navigationbar or toolbar using xib but I cannot able to set for the components which are created programatically in IOS7.So please tell me how to set the tintcolor or bartint as default.
2. Second one is In ios7 when ever I scroll the tableview up and down the tableview cell is getting selected with white colour.How to remove this selection colour.

Please help to resolve these two issues. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can set Tint Color Programatically using  `barTintColor` property
   You can try this,

   ```
   if ( [self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBarTintColor:)] ) 
   { 
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor]; 

   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But my question is I want to set the default color not a custom colours.So please let me know how to set default colour.

Comment: @Naresh, I believe setting the barTintColor to nil will give you the default color

`self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = nil`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor: [UIColor redColor]];
```